# Laravel9 - DB Query with one parent and 2 children not summing properly in selectraw

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have 3 tables : invoices, coletes, incasaris.

```
 Invoices ID     Coletes ID  Invoice_id  totaleuro       Incasaris ID Invoice_id i_totaleuro
          1               1       1          200                    1     1          200
                          2       1          100                    2     1          200
                          3       1          100
```

Basically, this query represents an invoice with the assigned parcels(coletes) and the receipts  (incasaris). I want to sum coletes.totaleuro and incasaris.totaleuro foreach invoice.

My query looks like this:

```
$invoices = DB::table('invoices')

->leftJoin('coletes','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
->leftJoin('incasaris','incasaris.i_plati_id','=','invoices.id')  
->selectRaw('
       sum(incasaris.i_totaleuro) as totalincasat,
      sum(coletes.totaleuro) as total,
        invoices.*
        
        ')
->orderBy('invoices.id')
->get();
```

The problem is that it should result in something as:

```
totalincasat : 400
       total : 400
```

But it's returning

```
  totalincasat: 1200
           total: 400
```

I do believe the problem lies in the fact that the query simply multiplies the correct result of incasaris (400) with the number of coletes that belong to the invoice (3 in this case) .

Any help would be appreciated I've been searching for a solution for a while on the web but I don't seem to find any similar post.
Thank you

Comment: Adding `->toSql()` (rather than `->get()`) might help you see what's going on.

Comment: select 
       sum(incasaris.i_totaleuro) as totalincasat,
        sum(coletes.totallei) as totallei,
      sum(coletes.totaleuro) as total,
        invoices.*,taga_cars.model, clients.name,clients.email
        
         from `invoices` left join `coletes` on `coletes`.`invoice_id` = `invoices`.`id` left join `clients` on `clients`.`id` = `invoices`.`id` left join `taga_cars` on `taga_cars`.`id` = `invoices`.`car_id` left join `incasaris` on `incasaris`.`i_plati_id` = `invoices`.`id` order by `invoices`.`id` asc        ///// I don't see anything wrong that would cause this issue

Comment: If you run that directly on the db, does it give the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

To return the total, you either need to sum in a subquery or group the result.

Using a subquery would be something like:

```php
DB::table('invoices')
->selectRaw('(SELECT SUM(totaleuro) FROM coletes WHERE coletes.invoice_id = invoices.id')
// and so on to add the other cols
```

Grouping would be something like:

```php
DB::table('invoices')
->leftJoin('coletes','coletes.invoice_id','=','invoices.id')
->sum('coletes.totaleuro')
->groupBy('invoices.id')
```